# EasyBlog Component missing image to URL to Facebook

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, facebook, easyblog

I have problem with sharing URL to Facebook is missing image with Easyblog.
I have upload cover image and there are pictures in article also.

I check with Sharing Debugger and I can see the image.

og:image    https://seekkhmer.com/images/easyblog_articles/1/b2ap3_large_0001.jpg

but I do not know which preview image doesn’t show.

Here is my website link
https://seekkhmer.com/index.php/news-easyblog/easyblog-installed-successfully.html

thank u

Comment: I test another plugin to integrate with Joomla's articles and share it to facebook. I can see the the image thumbnail on facebook. It seem my easyblog conflict with another software.

Answer (score 0):

I share Joomla article URL to Facebook and the image preview is working. I think it is not from server or image size. Maybe Easyblog conflict with another software.
thank u